# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, gradle, slf4j

I am using gradle to build my java project. 
After build and when I run the project on tomcat. I am getting error

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

I searched on internet to solution. But I still Could not find an answer. I have added log4j-1.2.17.jar, sl4j-api-1.7.5 , slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 to my lib. After go through the internet I added slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar also. And I have correctly added log4j.properties to src/main/resorces But still I could not find answer. Please help me.

Although I have this error I still can run the code mean I can add loggers. What are the effects of my codes because of that error?

Comment: what about the properties file?

Comment: Have you defined a binding? As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, it defaults to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.

Comment: @user2310289 I correctly add log4j.properties file to src/java/resorces using build.gradle file and now it's ok.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I used slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar here.

Comment: @user2310289 # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
 
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: When you say "run the project on Tomcat" does this mean you are using the Gradle Tomcat plugin?